# how to deal with negative in bquote expression in R

Tags: r

Hi I'm trying to write expression with an input variable, for example:

```
a=1
b=-2
bquote(y == .(a)*x+.(b))
```

The results is `y == 1 * x + -2`
not `y == 1 * x - 2` as I expected.

Is there anyway to deal with it? Thanks!

Comment: If I set a = 2 and b = 2 and use bquote(y == .(a)*x - .(b)) I get y == 2 * x - 2, but I do not know whether this is of any help.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of an elegant way, you can test for the sign and return a different symbol,

```
pm <- function(x){
  if(sign(x) == -1L) 
    return(bquote("-"~.(abs(x)))) else
    bquote("+"~.(x))
}

grid::grid.text(bquote(y== .(a)*x~.(pm(b))))
```